# How could i solve that kind of stful setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am complete cannot explain the issue in writing so I am trying to make it step by step

I have `Stfl widget page`

I am putting the following in its `initState methood`

```
 @override
  void initState(){
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState(() {});
      print('ok i rebuilt the state successfully');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Now if I change anything in `UI` before `Duration(seconds: 10)` which I registered in the previous method, it will successfully update the UI as expected.

Now, out of curiosity, I wanted to know if the previous method remains pending and executed after 10 sec if I exit the page or not , and I did the following

1- I log in to the page to register the function within `initstate`

2- I exited the page before the 10 seconds ran out

3- ok now I am on a different page waiting for  `print('ok I rebuilt the state successfully');` to print

4- well .. it is printed successfully as expected

Now I repeat the same steps with some changes like following

1- I log in to the page to register the function within `initstate`

2- I exited the page before the 10 seconds ran out

3- I log in to the page again before 10 sec is done

ok now it should print two times .. once for the first registered function and once for the second one
And yes it prints two times as expected but what I notice is if I make changes in UI before 10 sec is done so the UI will never update itself by the first registered function (Although I saw the process was successful in the console). but it updates it self by the second registered function.

now my question is why it does not update by first registered function . and how could i make it update ui by old pending `setState` method .

in the fact it happening either with `setState` or provider .

i need this behavior for many reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to the page, each time an new instance of the Widget is created. So the `setState` is run against the corresponding widget.

Imagine you have 2 of these on the same screen, you don't expect one to update the other one's state. Same thing happens here.

Also, I don't know if you're doing the `future.delayed` to test this. If you're doing this in your app, I suggest you check the `mounted` property before setting state, so you prevent setting state on a disposed Widget which can cause issues and exceptions.

something like

```dart
 Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {});
      print('ok i rebuilt the state successfully');
    });
```

Comment: thanks .. is there a way to keep the old instance of my stfl .. so every time i visit the page it keep the old instance ?

Comment: Highly advise against that. You should instead keep the data for that screen elsewhere and pass it on to the widget. State of the widget should only live until the widget is disposed. If you want it to live beyond its life, the state should be pulled up, to the parent. If you have state that need to go even above the app, like if your app stops and restarted, and you expect the data to be there, (many apps do) then this state should be managed by a different entity, likely outside of your widget tree. Like a service from GetIt, could be saved to storage and loaded on demand .etc.

Comment: Highly thanks for telling me this .. i appreciate it i wasn't know that